# Does bootstrap glyphicons go through their containers borders?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

Is that Bootstrap's problem, or the glyphicons itselves? It's irritating, because I want to use these glyphicons in a large size on mobile phones, and it screws up the horizontal align.

I attached a picture, so you can see what is the problem exactly.

[image: Why is this??]

Comment: can you make a fiddle for your code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: I think its the container that's causing the problem. you might want to reduce the size of glyphicons.